# How to create a weighted graph from .gml file in python igraph

Tags: python, graph, import, igraph, weighted

I have a .gml file (Nor graphML) which has details of my nodes and edges. I am importing the graph in python making use of the igraph library by the following code:

```
g = igraph.read("mydata.gml")"
```

I have given values in my .gml file for edges:

```
edge
[
source 1
target 0
value 6.25
]
```

Also the file starts with

```
graph
[
  directed 0
  weighted 1
```

However when I check, g.is_weighted() it returns false. How do I make igraph take the values in .gml file as weights for the edges of the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `is_weighted()` method simply checks whether your graph has an edge attribute named `weight`. In your case, you don't because the values from the GML file are stored in the `value` edge attribute, not in `weight`. The solution is either to replace every occurrence of `value` with `weight` in your input file, or to rename the attribute in igraph after you have loaded the file as follows:

```
g.es["weight"] = g.es["value"]
del g.es["value"]
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to incorporate weights while plotting graphs in igraph? Probably by different edge lengths?

Comment: Some layout algorithms can take edge weights into account to some extent; see, for instance, `Graph.layout_fruchterman_reingold`. However, since weights usually represent sets of constraints that cannot be satisfied at the same time, these algorithms are not guaranteed to respect all of them.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the help. Solved my problem to an extent :)